# javapoet : comment into an interface

Tags: java, javapoet

I would like to know if it is possible to add **comments into an interface** with JavaPoet ?

Using `addJavadoc()` method could be enough, but I need both of them (javadoc and comments) for the files I have to generate.

I'm currently looking for a way to do it on the JavaPoet github but I don't see any addComment() method **for interfaces** or something else who could do it...

Comment: have you tried: addCode("// my comment here;") ?

Comment: There is no `addCode()` method for interfaceBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to comment the method of the interface, something like this should work:

```
    TypeSpec.interfaceBuilder("MyInterface")
        .addJavadoc("Bla Bla Bla")
        .addMethod(MethodSpec.methodBuilder("testMethodWithComment")
                             .addJavadoc("blub blub blub")
                             .build())
        .build();
```

will generate this code:

```
    /**
     * Bla Bla Bla */
    public interface MyInterface {
      /**
       * blub blub blub */
      void testMethodWithComment();
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to write something like this : imagine that I have 2 fields and 2 getter methods of these fields, with already Javadoc for each of them. I wanted to add simple comments like `// Fields`  and `// getters methods` above them.

Comment: I think this is currently just not possible, your answer is what I was doing before I ask. I'll tag it to 'accepted'. If we absolutely need comments into interface, we should create an issue on their gitlhub. Thanks to you for helping me :)